# List view algin horizontal CSS for mobile

Tags: css, html, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I have list of data which i am binding using Knockoutjs,Now comes for CSS part, i need to align it horizontal.I am not much good in CSS.I have three images and username so i want to align it in Horizontal for my Mobile app below is my code kindly suggest me.

```
<ul style="list-style: none;" data-role="listview" id="hierarchical-listview" data-bind="foreach:UserProfile">
<li style="background-color:#FFF">
 <div style="width:100%;">
 <div style="width:50%">
 <div style="padding-left:20px;padding-top:10px">
 <span data-bind="text:UserId" style="display:none;"></span>
 <span data-bind="text:Username"></span>
 <img class="profileimage" data-bind="attr: { src: UserImage }" style="width:60px;height:60px;float:left!important;" />
 <img data-bind="attr: { src: UserProfileImage }" style="width:30px;height:30px;float:left!important;" />
</div>
</div>
<div style="width:50%;float:left;margin: 0px -20px;">
<img data-bind="attr: { src: UserPostedImage }" style="width:30px;height:30px;float:left!important;" />
<input type="checkbox" class="listcheckbox km-widget km-icon km-check" data-bind="checked:UserSelected" />
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the `float` from your `img` containers and the parent `div` containers.

Provide `display: inline-block` to all and then `vertical-align: middle`.

So your `img` elements should look something like:

```
<img class="profileimage" data-bind="attr: { src: UserImage }" style = "width:60px; height:60px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;" />
```